# how to redirect page to another URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

user request example URL

http://example.com/test

instead error 404

redirect to URL

http://example.com/index.php?test

Sorry for poor English

Comment: Use Google before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

For true redirect, and not only rewrite, use `[R=301,L,QSA]` Flags